# Which is better? - USE DATABASE Vs DATABASE.TABLE_NAME in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am working in an `Multiple Shared Database environment(MySQL)` where I need to switch between multiple database often.

Lets say My Main DataBase is `MainDB`.

Also there are Shared Databases for each user say `ShardDB1, ShardDB2 ...`.

Since I am using `JAVA Connection pooling`, I have to get the connection to execute while executing each and every query and release it to pool as soon as finish executing it.

I tried the below methods and i couldn't notice any performance difference or any issues.

1. Every time i want to use SharedDB, I will switch to SharedDB like `USE ShardDB1;` and after performing query execution again switch back to MainDB like `USE MainDB;`
2. Writing Query like `"Select * from "+ ShardDB1 +".TABLE_NAME where ....";`

`2nd method is easier` for me to use in code. But before i push it to production, i wanted to know if there's any issue(especially performance) in using the 2nd method. I googled for it, but couldn't find any. Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real difference for performance. In the first case, the server edits the request, adding the prefix itself. In the second one, the prefix is a java variable. If there is a difference, it is about 0.1 ms, or less.

USE DATABASE statement is a shortcut for the developer to write his requests.
When working on multiple database, you should better not use this statement, but prefix your tables with the db name. Then, if you forget to specify the name in a request, you do not take the risk to alter the wrong database.